# docker run doesn't run my script in /etc/profile.d/

Tags: bash, docker

I have my own script in **/etc/profile.d/myscript.sh** (mounted from the host) prepared in the container, but it fails to execute when docker run

```
$ docker run -it -v /etc/profile.d/myscript.sh:/etc/profile.d/myscript.sh centos7 myscript arg1
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"myscript\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.
```

if docker run without any command, then I directly attach into the container, the script works.
The script is there under /etc/profile.d/, and I am able to run myscript inside the container

```
[root@c5f121d37ca5 /]# myscript
Usage:
myscript [arg1] [arg2]
...
[root@c5f121d37ca5 /]#
[root@c5f121d37ca5 /]# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

I have no clue why my script is not executable with docker run.
my Dockerfile for the image is just basic things which does yum update, install some pkg.
Appreciate if someone please shed me some light on how to make myscript executable at docker run?  or anything i need to work on the dockerfile?

---

I also added the path of the script in Dockerfile and re-ran but still got the same error.

```
ENV PATH=$PATH:/etc/profile.d/
```

I checked the /etc/profile.d/ is in the PATH inside the container.

```
$ docker run centos7 env | grep PATH
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/etc/profile.d/
```

Comment: There are some weird stuff in your output. 

First you mount myscript.sh but give myscript to docker as command.
Second /etc/profile.d is not in your PATH, so running myscript should tell 'command not found'.

Comment: What's the intended relationship between `myscript.sh` and `myscript`?

Comment: myscript.sh and myscript are same, just execute it without the .sh extension

Comment: thanks @GökhanŞengün for pointing out, how to make it works?

Comment: I just added the path of the script in Dockerfile `ENV PATH=$PATH:/etc/profile.d/` , and re-ran but still got the same error.   I checked the path `PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/etc/profile.d/`

Comment: Alternatives are. 1) `docker run --rm -v /etc/profile.d/myscript.sh:/etc/profile.d/myscript.sh nginx:1.10 bash -c 'export PATH=$PATH:/etc/profile.d/; myscript.sh'` 2) `docker run --rm -v /etc/profile.d/myscript.sh:/etc/profile.d/myscript.sh nginx:1.10 /etc/profile.d/myscript.sh`

Comment: Using `ENV` in Dockerfile should also work, you just need double quotes.

`ENV PATH="$PATH:/etc/profile.d/"`

Comment: Thank you @GökhanŞengün. 1) double quotes on `ENV PATH="$PATH:/etc/profile.d/` doesn't work too.  2) if `docker run` with the command full path `/etc/profile.d/myscript.sh`, it can locate the script, but this time error `starting container process caused "exec: \"/etc/profile.d/myscript.sh\": permission denied": unknown.`.  It is weird, i can successfully myscript inside the container without any problem...